# How to send a temporary PHP file as attachment using PHPMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I'm trying to send a temporary file created by my PHP code as an email attachment.

I'm using PHPMailer - this works OK when I try to add attachments to physical files .. I'm not sure what I need to do to attach a temporary file ..

Here's some code:

```
require_once("class/BuildPass.php");
require_once("../../Utilities/PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

// Prepare email 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->SetFrom("address@mycompany.com", "My Company");
$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->Subject = "Here's your email with file attachment";
$mail->CharSet="UTF-8";

// Retrieve the email template required
$message = file_get_contents('pass/email_templates/Event200613.html');  // HTML Mail template
// Replace the % with the actual information
$message = str_replace('%name%', $name, $message);
$message = str_replace('%email%', $email, $message);
// Add embedded images
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("Images/strip.png", "strip");
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage("Images/logo5787924_md.jpg", "Company_logo");

//generate a new pass
$newPass = BuildPass::createPass($name, $email, $barcode, $error);  // This function creates an Apple Passbook file with .pkpass extension ...

$mail->MsgHTML($message);

$mail->Send();
```

This code works fine for me .. It sends an HTML email with images embedded properly .. (Note - $name and $email were defined in an input form) ..

Now I'd like to attach the temporary file $newPass. 
I cannot simply use

```
$mail->AddAttachment($newPass);  // This crashes
```

I presume I need to create a temporary file with a defined pathname and then add this attachment - however I can't find the right info on how to do it ..

Any help is much appreciated ..

Andrew

`var_dump($newPass)`;

```
object(BuildPass)#2 (7) { ["keyPath":"BuildPass":private]=> string(89) "/mnt/stor08-wc1-ord1/738827/dev.myserver.com/web/content/path/pass" ["sourcePath":"BuildPass":private]=> string(96) "/mnt/stor08-wc1-ord1/738827/dev.myserver.com/web/content/path/pass/source" ["workFolder":"Pass":private]=> string(18) "/tmp/51a5d3795c59e" ["ID":"Pass":private]=> string(13) "blahblah" ["content"]=> array(14) { lots of stuff } } } } ["passBundleFile"]=> string(39) "/tmp/51a5d3795c59e/51a5d3795c59e.pkpass" }
```

Comment: are you uploading desired file via form, or you want just generate any file that contains $newPass and send it along with your email? I just re-read your question, I see where the file is from.

Comment: Hi - I'm not uploading the file via form - I just want to generate the file containing $newPass and send it attached to the email ..

Comment: Could you please post var_dump($newPass);

Comment: Hi - var_dump($newPass);  outputs the following ..

Comment: [edit] your question and post it there :)

Comment: Hi - var_dump($newPass);  outputs the following .. object(BuildPass)#2 (7) { ["keyPath":"BuildPass":private]=> string(89) "/mnt/stor08-wc1-ord1/738827/dev.myserver.com/web/content/path/pass" ["sourcePath":"BuildPass":private]=> string(96) "/mnt/stor08-wc1-ord1/738827/dev.myserver.com/web/content/path/pass/source" ["workFolder":"Pass":private]=> string(18) "/tmp/51a5d3795c59e" ["ID":"Pass":private]=> string(13) "blahblah" ["content"]=> array(14) { lots of stuff } } } } ["passBundleFile"]=> string(39) "/tmp/51a5d3795c59e/51a5d3795c59e.pkpass" }

Comment: as you can see the file you are looking for is "/tmp/51a5d3795c59e/51a5d3795c59e.pkpass" of course it is generated each time the function is called. Can you please refer me a link where did you get `BuildPass.php` Because I am sure that whoever created that class created method to get path to created file.

Comment: Hi - BuildPass.php is a long file I've created that produces Passbook .pkpass files .. But for this example it could be any kind of temporary file that I want to attach to an email ..

Comment: So you are familiar with `BuildPass.php`, now you just create new method in class to return temporary file. eg: `$newPass->getPath()` should return `"/tmp/51a5d3795c59e/51a5d3795c59e.pkpass"` so you just use it as your desired string for function `AddAttachment`, `$mail->AddAttachment($newPass->getFilePath());`